# whats better, giving hard coded height or using weight parameter to set View parameters..?

Tags: android, orientation, layoutparams

I usually give fixed height in order to avoid views getting overlapped on orientation change,  But is giving weight is better than this..?, share it if there are better ways to give LayoutParameter.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It completely depends on situations, like when my view should cover a part of width and height available on screen, then I would opt for weight and when it should be fixed in dimensions irrespective of width, height then use fixed layout co-ordinates.